# C: Display a system generic dialog box requesting password on Linux

Tags: c, linux, dialog, passwords, debian

I am on a Debian Linux OS, developping a file securing application in C.
I am trying to request a password to a user for authentication before executing some code. I wish to provide a system generic password window (i.e, the once that appear when we are asked to enter root password by update-manager during update install or mounting a file-system).
I tried `systemd-aask-password` and `dialog --passwordbox` shell commands using `popen()` to run from my C code to request for password. However, both of these commands works within the shell, not when triggered via a desktop launcher.

[image]

Is there a way to request the password via a dia;og window appearing outside the shell? The aspproach may use shelll-script, python, perl or generic C code, so that I cam integrate with my existing C program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `zenity`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);
int pclose(FILE *stream);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *cmd;
    char result[32];

    cmd = popen("zenity --password", "r");
    if (cmd == NULL) {
        perror("popen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd)) {
        result[strcspn(result, "\r\n")] = 0; 
        printf("password: %s\n", result);
    }
    pclose(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```